# How do I check a response against a Regex with Codeception?

Tags: codeception

I want to do functional tests with Codeception on some ajax Requests. As some of them are time dependend or random I just want to validate, that the response matches the expected format. For Example I expect one result to be a 5 digit number lower than 5000. Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use REST module, it has some useful methods for inspecting JSON and XML responses.

```
$I->sendPOST('/ajax/', $params);
$I->seeResponseMatchesJsonType([
  'number' => 'integer:>10000:<50000'
]);
```

http://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST#seeResponseMatchesJsonType

Comment: That function can perform all the checks I want on a json. But unfortunately my response is no json but only plain text :-( I need something like `$I->seeResponseMatches()`